# How to handle the character spacing in the string drawn using GDI+ in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+

How to handle the space between characters in string drawn using GDI+ in MFC, I am using:

```
graphics.SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintAntiAlias);  
drawing.DrawTextGDI(...)
```

to draw the string, but I am getting space of almost 3-4 px after each and every character, its clearly visible when I zoomed the drawn string.

Comment: Your pseudo code does not provide much information. To achieve anti-aliasing GDI+ has to make the edges fuzzy, it usually extends out 1 or 2 pixels. You can disable anti-aliasing if you want.

Comment: Please arrange your code in a manner that uses `graphics.DrawString` instead. I've never heard of `DrawTextGDI`, nor I see any relevant documentation of it on the Internet. And I've even searched the MFC source on my machine for it, but i had not found anything. It doesn't even seem to be part of GDI+, looking to its name! Was it implemented by you?

Comment: Yup...by mistake I put ds name...under this API m drawing string using GDI +